# How do I run instrumented tests of a module without an accompanying app?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have made a library project consisting of an Android module and no application. This module relies on Android-specific functionality.

How do I run these tests with Firebase?

It seems like Firebase requires an app apk and a test apk, while I only have a test apk (`*-androidTest.apk`). I normally run tests locally without issues using `./gradlew connectedCheck`.

Comment: Just do a simple app with your library

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Will try that! I can hopefully make some progress using a dummy app. Thanks!